# custom pages give 404 error title in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, page-title

I'm running a site powered by WordPress with extra pages...
To integrate these pages with the WordPress theme I use this code:

```
<?php
$blog_longd='Title'; // page title
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp-blog-header.php');
get_header();
?>

html code

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
?>
```

This works fine, however page title shows always 404 Error Page (not "Title").

It seems that $wp-query->is_404 is always set to true. I tried overriding this value but it doesn't seem to work. I tried fixing it by putting header status 200 above function get_header()..also it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I know it has been a long time since you asked but I had the problem and here is the solution.

```
<?php
require('./wp-config.php');

$wp->init();
$wp->parse_request();
$wp->query_posts();
$wp->register_globals();
$wp->send_headers();

get_header();

echo "HELLO WORLD";

get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe clumsy, but if you implement the `wp_title` filter, you can change the title to what you want. You can add this code to the header of each custom page:

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'replace_title');
function replace_title() {
   return 'My new title';
}
```

If you want it a bit cleaner, use a smarter version of this filter to a plugin, and set only the global variable (here `$override_title`) in your page:

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'replace_title_if_global');
function replace_title_if_global($title) {
   global $override_title;
   if ($override_title) {
      return $override_title;
   }
   return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is code in the file class-wp.php:

```
function handle_404() {
...
    // Don't 404 for these queries if they matched an object.
    if ( ( is_tag() || is_category() || is_tax() || is_author() || is_post_type_archive() ) && $wp_query->get_queried_object() ) {
        status_header( 200 );
        return;
    }
...
}
```

that handles 404 status for various of pages.

The stack of functions of this code is:

```
1) wp-blog-header.php:14, require()
2) function.php:775, wp()
3) class-wp.php:525, WP->main()
4) class-wp.php:491, handle_404()
```

So you have two ways to handle the situation:

1)

```
require('wp-blog-header.php');
function status_header( 200 );
```

2) more correct would be insert your own function here

```
if ( your_own_function() || ((is_tag() || is_category() || is_tax() || is_author() || is_post_type_archive() ) && $wp_query->get_queried_object()) ) {
```

that returns `true` when your custom page is requested